# Does Bitcoin Core v0.17.0 run on native wayland?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

I'm trying to run bitcoin core v0.17.0 on Wayland on Fedora 29. When I run bitcoin-qt I receive

> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.

Running with QT_WPA_PLATFORM=wayland yields

> QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

Is there a configuration change that will allow bitcoin core v0.17.0 to run on native wayland? Or what is the best way to provide a bug report to the core devs regarding wayland issues?